# ¿Como mostrar los resultados de un summary de R en un Markdown (word) de una forma más ordenada?

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown

Este código de R Markdown es para poder generar un archivo Word y la salida son ciertos gráficos, pero además quiero mostrar algunos datos (comando summary), pero la salida de estos es bastante desordenada en Word, queda muy poco entendible, ¿alguno sabrá como lograr que estos datos queden en una tabla o algo más ordenado? Por favor.

```
lista_total= list()
for (i in 1:44){
    dfn=df_unido_n %>%
        filter(NombreCentral == nmb[i])
    lista_total[[i]]<-dfn
}    
for (i in 1:44){
    x=lista_total[[i]]$POTENCIA_BRUTA_MWH
    y=lista_total[[i]]$CONCENTRACION_CO2_TON
    ts.plot(x, ylab = "Potencia bruta", main = nmb[i])
    ts.plot(y, ylab = "Concentracion CO2",  main = nmb[i])
    plot(x~y , xlab = "Potencia bruta", ylab = "Concentracion CO2",  main = nmb[i])
    print(lm(x~y-1))
    print(summary(lista_total[[i]]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando la función `pander()` de la librería `pander::`. Tiene métodos para muchas clases de objetos, incluidos los sumarios de un data.frame. Esta función da formato `markdown` a la salida, luego `pandoc` se encarga silenciosamente de convertirlo en una tabla de Word.

La salida no siempre es perfecta, depende mucho de la cantidad de columnas que estén en el sumario, pero es más ordenada que la salida en texto de `summary()`.

En general cuando estoy haciendo sumarios descriptivos grandes prefiero hacer salida en `html` en lugar de Word o .pdf. Al no tener paginado se resuelven muchos problemas de tablas cortadas, etc. Depende de como tengas que almacenar/compartir el reporte, no siempre se puede.

En tu código podrías modificar la última línea del segundo bucle:

```
pander(summary(lista_total[[i]]))
```

Creo que el print en ese caso no es estrictamente necesario, pero no recuerdo bien.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona en parte (me deja algo distinto el summary), pero igual queda algo desordenado, en la consola se ve bien, pero en el markdown queda algo raro, lo intente con pandoc.date y algo mejoró

Comment: Otra posibilidad es hacer un sumario personalizado, calcular los estadísticos que te interesan y ubicarlos en un data.frame. Después podrías usar `knitr::kable()` o algo por el estilo para sacar ese data.frame a markdown. De ese modo tendrías más control sobre la salida.